# Adding UserControl dynamically map

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, esri, esri-arc-engine

At WPF ESRI, we can add picture to the coordinate ,but we can not add with user control And I want to add "user control" to specify place at runtime. I hope that you understood what I mean.

```
        BitmapImage Bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(st));

        PictureMarkerSymbol pms = new PictureMarkerSymbol()
        {
            Source = Bi
        };

        var graphic = new Graphic() { Geometry = new MapPoint(x, y) };
        graphic.Symbol = pms;
        MarkerGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
```

Comment: *I'm sorry my english is not good*... I'm sorry, but you'll have to do better than that. We need you to clearly tell us what your requirements are and what your problem is. For now, I have voted to close this question because it is unclear what you want. I will of course remove my close vote if and when you edit your question to provide clearer details. Perhaps you could get a fried to help you with the English?

Comment: How do I add the UserControl to dynamically coordinate

Comment: Firstly, that is *not* editing your question and secondly, that is no clearer than before... it's not even English... *to dynamically coordinate*... to dynamically coordinate what? I am *not* getting into a line by line discussion. Please use the 'edit' button to edit your question to provide further details so that we can understand what you want.

Comment: At WPF ESRI,  we can add   picture to the coordinate ,but we can not add with user control And I want to add "user control" to specify place  at runtime. I hope that you understood what I mean.